# Is there a DAX Query to extract values from a different column using a repeated (row wise) ID number as a reference?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 tables.

Table 1 - Consolidated assignment data. This has 3 columns.

Employee number (unique ID given to each employee). Every time there is an assignment tagged for this employee, His number will be captured here along with assignment start date and end date. (The other 2 columns)

So, The employee code is repeated in multiple rows

Table 2 is EM data it is a database of employees.

It has 2 columns. Employee Number, Employee ID. No repetitions here. Both are unique for each employee.

I want to bring GGIDs to first table.

The code i used is:

EmpID =
VAR EmployeeNo = 'Overall Assignment report'[Employee No]
RETURN
MAXX (
FILTER (
'EM data',
'EM data'[Employee ] = EmployeeNo
),
'Overall Assignment report'[Employee ID]
)

Someone please help

Comment: do you mean you want to bring EEID's to the first table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a few ways.

1. You can merge the two tables in power query on the employee number, and then bring in the EEID
2. You can create a relationship(in the model view) between the two tables on the Employee Number fields.
3. You can create a calculated column in table1 with the LOOKUPVALUE function to retrieve the EEID from the second table.